# Edit a deep part of an object with string key with dots

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, object

i need to merge two objects, where one is a part with some changes of an old one.

So, we have an object that looks like this (example):

```json
{
   "item": {
      "data": "some text here",
      "info": {
         "test": {
            "roles": [
               "admin"
            ],
            "index": 0 
         }
      }
   }
}
```

and then we have a string that looks like this: `"item.info.test"`
and also we have a new object, that is actually a part of an old one.

```js
{
   "roles": [
      "admin"
   ],
   "index": 5  
}
```

how can we replace last subkey with a new object?

i tried using obj[key][subkey] etc, but its impossible to do this with lots of keys.

Comment: It is not clear what you're asking (at least not to me). `"data.info.test"` is not a valid path. Did you mean `"item.info.test"` ? That will make more sense.

Comment: oh yea, `"item.info.test"`, sorry

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to deal with object keys not with array indexes, you could do something like this:

```js
const data = {
   "item": {
      "data": "some text here",
      "info": {
         "test": {
            "roles": [
               "admin"
            ],
            "index": 0 
         }
      }
   }
}
const path = 'item.info.test';
const replacement = {
   "roles": [
      "admin"
   ],
   "index": 5  
};

const pathArray = path.split('.');
const lastKey = pathArray.pop();
const penultimate = pathArray.reduce((a, c) => a[c], data);
penultimate[lastKey] = replacement;
console.log(data);
```

This approach mutates the original object (`data`) and I've probably made it more complicated then it has to be.

Comment: well, it works but it says `Type 'undefined' cannot be used as an index type.` (typescript)

Comment: using this code does not replace it, it creates a new one with same name but with same level as "index"